# Post a request and receive a response using Flatbuffers instead of json in web services? Suggest link to such an example

Tags: json, serialization, flatbuffers

I have seen some posts but not getting any example for this use case, here is a link which I have referred to [this](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/FlatBuffer). I have read some blogs also but all was in vain.

Comment: Note that requests for off-site resources are off-topic here. Would you read the Help Centre when you get a moment?

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly the same as using JSON, except that instead of using a serialized JSON string you will send a binary array of bytes (meaning it's important your `content-type` is `binary/octet-stream`, not utf-8 or whatever).

This has examples on how to construct and access the byte array (make sure to select JavaScript or whichever language you're using): http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html